# How many nodes can be connected to SQL Server 2014 Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

My Windows application's backend is SQL Server 2014 Express which is installed on Windows 7 Pro, and I have configured it to connect over internet with SQL Server  authentication with one user `SA` only. From how many computers I can connect to SQL Server 2014 Express? Is there any limit?

Answer (score 0):

From here: [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server)

> User connections      32,767

You can determine it using a code too:

```
select @@MAX_CONNECTIONS;
```

But your possible problem is not the limit of user connections, but 1Gb limit for server memory, that should be divided between these 32,767 connections.